# Function names and parameters in matlab variables

Tags: matlab, eval

In my matlab m-file I am using some logic (string concat) to build variables like this:

```
c = 'CalcPrediction(1,10)'
```

That means I have a string that is a function and some parameters. How can I do that function call?

Trying run(c) results in:

```
>> run(c)
??? Error using ==> run at 71
CalcPrediction(1,10) not found.
```

Note: run(c) works fine if there is no parameters. E.g.
    c='CalcPrediction';
    run(c);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `eval()` instead of `run()`

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing the script it's hard to generalize, but...

Where squareRoot is an m-file containing only :`y=sqrt(x)`

Then executing :

`x=[2,0];`

`c='squareRoot';`

`run(c);`

gives :

`y =`

`1.4142         0`

This example is to say you can define the script to use a declared variable (`x` in this case) and then declare the variable before running the script.

Without the script I don't know what you're doing with the parameters.  If this doesn't answer your question, post your script.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use [str2func](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html). This function takes a string and returns a function handler that can be called with your parameters. Check out the examples on the linked page.

```
fh = str2func('CalcPrediction')
fh(1, 10)
```

Comment: eval is a more accurate solution to the question. It takes as an input the exact string (in variable c) that markussvensson wants to use. (As an aside, the @-operator, as in fh=@CalcPrediction, is simpler than using str2func.)